# Database is not connecting to visual studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio

i have created a project in visual studio and created database in sql server. the problem is my database is not connecting to sql

i have tried creating new database still not working. here check following images for understanding. i think its simple string issue but i am confused here. in my sql server the server name is different. and in visual studio when i click on modify connection then the server name is different. i actually bought this software so i think this pc is new so need to change server names i think. check screenshots.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFIo1.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, share the code in your post so we can give a better help. Thanks!

Comment: ok here is my string code

<add name="MobileRecharge" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-50D89F5\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MobileRecharge;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>

Comment: somehow now my database is not showing cross. bcoz in sql server the server name was different and in visual studio under dtabase connections the server name was different. so i copied the server name from sql server and went to visual studio click on modify connection and pasted the server name i copied which is now exactly same in both places maybe thats why the database is now not showing cross sign. but when i click on run it on google chrome and i get error

Answer (score 0):

Connection string will be a mix of network path and credentials.

The reason is "The network path defined is not accessible in the current context".

See the properties of the connection and try connecting to the IP

Comment: give me few minutes. i am going to send a drop box link in which i will include all screenshots of my program and issue so you guys can easily understand

Comment: @malikbilal no, please dont! :D Edit your question, add code in text format (not pictures! helps with copy&paste to provide an answer), use the formating tool. DropBox files are not persistant and wont help future readers, when you deleted your files. Also, please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i totally understand your point. but how do i show you the errors ? i cannot copy and paste errors page now. the screenshots are only about the layout so you can better understand the issue

Comment: now i have made my software in default. so now database is showing cross sign. here is my new string

<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MobileRecharge" connectionString="Data Source=ADMIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MobileRecharge;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>